# Easier way to convert pipe separated string into variables and values?

Tags: c#, string, split, key-value

The settings for a program I am writing are delivered as a string separated by the pipe symbol. The code I have created below splits the string into its name/value pairs and then manually goes through them in a loop using a long list of if statements to create a variable and assign it its value. Is there an easier way?

```
string a = "en=1|ty=1|ns=0|bs=1|rw=0"; //....lots more of these


string[] b = a.Split('|');

foreach (string c in b)
{
      string[] d = c.Split('=');

      if (d[1] == "en") { string en = d[2]; }
      if (d[1] == "ty") { string ty = d[2]; }
      //...on and on and on
 }
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary instead of variables.

Comment: are You sure, first element is '1' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you really need to handle each variables individually, a dictionary would be a more generic way to handle the values:

```
var valueDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (string a in "en=1|ty=1|ns=0|bs=1|rw=0".Split("|"))
{
    string[] b = a.Split('=');
    valueDictionary[b[0]] = b[1]; //Your example was 1 base but I think it's should be a 0 base
}
```

Then you can access the value using:

```
string enValue = valueDictionary["en"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary like the following code:

```js
string a = "en=1|ty=1|ns=0|bs=1|rw=0";
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
a.Split('|').Select(c => c.Split('=')).ToList().ForEach((val) => { dictionary[val[0]] = val[1]; });
```